# Independent jquery functions execute consecutively when one is called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My problems seems basic, yet I have tried a lot of different ways of putting these functions on one html file to no avail. The problem is that, when the 1st function is called, the second also runs, leaving me with the results of the second function all the time. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, please help. Here is the code in question.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () { // Make sure the elements are loaded on the page
    // Listen for a click event on the button
    $('#buttonON').click(funct);
    $('#buttonOFF').click(funct2);  
});
// Now define the function
function favfunct(e) {
    // Stop the page from "following" the button (ie. submitting the form)
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Insert AJAX call here...
        $.ajax("carstatusupd.php", {
        // Pass our data to the server
        data: { "username" : "sibusiso", "caron" : "1", "caroff" : "0"},
        // Pass using the appropriate method
        method: "POST",
        // When the request is completed and successful, run this code.
        success: function (response) {
                // Successfully added to favorites. JS code goes here for this condition.
            }
    });

function funct2(e) {
    // Stop the page from "following" the button (ie. submitting the form)
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Insert AJAX call here...
    $.ajax("carstatusupd.php", {
        // Pass our data to the server
        data: { "username" : "sibusiso", "caron" : "0", "caroff" : "1"},
        // Pass using the appropriate method
        method: "POST",
        // When the request is completed and successful, run this code.
        success: function (response) {
                // Successfully added to favorites. JS code goes here for this condition.
            }
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of `$('#buttonON').click(funct);`, don't you mean to have `$(#buttonON').click(favfunct);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted the closing brace from the function `favfunct()`.

Comment: it was simply a case of pasting the code into an editor (jsfiddle.net) with a "cleanup" button in it - as suspected it instantly showed that `funct2` was incorrectly nested inside `favfunct`.

Answer (score -2):

```
 Please use this,

 <script>

 $(document).ready(function () { 

       function funOne(){
        };

       function funTwo(){
        };


    $('#buttonON').live('click',function(){
        funOne();
    });
    $('#buttonOFF').live('click',function(){
       funTwo();        
    });

 });


 NOte: initialize function before use and initialize them into document ready.
```

Comment: Wow, there is _so_ much bad advice here, please _don't_ use *any* of this!  1. functions are hoisted automatically, so they don't need to be declared first.  2.  `.live` is obsolete, replaced with `.on`, and not needed here.  3.  the function wrappers around the `funOne` and `funTwo` callbacks are not only superfluous but prevent the event object and `this` context from being passed to the real event handlers.